# What hair-care benefits come from adding fruit or fruit-extracts to shampoo?

Tags: hair, fruit, cosmetics

Shampoo manufacturers seem to be very keen to tell us about the all the fruit and fruit-extracts they put in their product. I suspect that the hair-care actually comes from the other ingredients they put in it.

Is shampoo with added fruit really better for hair-care than shampoo with no fruit?

For the purposes of this question, let's leave the smell to one side. Yes, fruity shampoo smells nice, but unless shampoo would smell bad without it, its not really a hair-care benefit.

For example:
* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ztPddsZp14
* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoV_xfvTViA
* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJgBWJwDC08
* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDmGQsuxguU
* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsfNXj9s-iY
* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0bUZIXGIJc
* http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NW2GT2VQCw4

Comment: Do any of these manufacturers actually claim it has hair-care benefits? If so, can you summarize what they say? I don't feel like watching all of  those videos.

Comment: @sumelic From Garnier's website: "A full range of hair care formulated with a power dose of active fruit concentrate and ceramides to make every inch 10x stronger.*" This seems to imply the fruit concentrate is helping with strengthening the hair. Admittedly, the word order allows some ambiguity (it could be just the ceramides make the hair stronger). [Ref](http://www.garnierusa.com/products/haircare/grow-strong.aspx)

Comment: @called2voyage When you see ambiguous wording like this it's probably for a reason.

Comment: billpg, to clarify, are you interested whether any fruit that has been used in a topical hair-care product has beneficial effects on the hair (aside from smell)? Or are do you want to address particularly what Garnier and Herbal Essences uses?